# Using NodeJS as a multi-view rendering microservice

Tags: php, node.js, proxy, reverse-proxy, isomorphic-javascript

Is it possible to inject a NodeJS isomorphic application onto another website (eg something running PHP 5.3/Wordpress) by cURL'ing (or using some other kind of HTTP GET) to a Node webserver as part of the original site's HTTP response?

For example, I'm trying to be able to load mywebsite.com (PHP/WordPress) which has routes/pages built from the WordPress CMS, but on a particular page (or set of pages) include a NodeJS isomorphic application as part of its body content.

Ideally, this is the sort of architecture we'd have:

1. mywebsite.com - PHP/WordPress (first server)
2. mywebsite.com/application - Wrapped by PHP/WordPress but includes a
   NodeJS isomorphic application (second server) rendering the "home"
   view with a link to "subpage" within the app, also retrieves data
   from an API on a third server
3. mywebsite.com/application/subpage -
   Wrapped by PHP/WordPress but includes the NodeJS applications
   "subpage" view

As you can see, though PHP/WordPress handles the main site, a NodeJS server would distribute a centralized application to potentially multiple/hundreds of websites.

*My current implementation works doing this:*

**First Server (PHP/WordPress):**

1. Receive HTTP GET for a WordPress "page"
2. Begin rendering page
3. Encounter HTTP GET request for Node server

**Second Server (NodeJS/Express):**

4. Receive HTTP GET for a route that's wrapped in an API fetch (Third Server)
5. Receive API response and respond to HTTP GET from First Server with the appropriate view

**First Server (PHP/WordPress):**

6. Receive response from NodeJS, finish rendering rest of page and respond to browser

*However, the existing two challenges/questions are:*

1. How to generate usable and search-engine indexable routes (defined within the Node application) originating from requests to the First Server
2. How to transmit client-side logic from Node for the appropriate view back to the client
3. Assuming we're able to make this as speedy as possible, what security or unnecessary risks does this method take?
4. Is this a much more convoluted way of doing something that can be done simpler via another method?  **Bonus:** What's this method/idea/process even be called?

Part of the reason I can't just rebuild the original site wholly in Node is because our company currently supports hundreds of websites for clients built with varying web languages/frameworks/server-versions, and we want to be able to distribute the same product to each regardless of destination constraints.

Thank you in advance!